# Find a bijective function between rationals.

Tags: analysis

Give an explicit example of a bijective function $f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ such that $f(x)>x^3$ for each x.

My approach :=

Consider $f(x)=x^3+1$.

Then $f$ is one-one but not onto.

Since 3 has no pre-image.

Now I am unable to construct.

Comment: Interesting problem. Where is it coming from?

Comment: I'd start by defining $f(n)=n^3+1$ for integers.  Thus, $f(0)=1, f(1)=2$ for example.  Now write down the linear bijection $[0,1]\to [1,2]$ and so on.

Comment: This  problem is taken from  the book Steven G. Krantz.

Comment: Nice function @lulu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :** Define $f : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by $$f(x)=\Big((\lfloor x \rfloor+1)^3-\lfloor x \rfloor^3 \Big)\lbrace x \rbrace + \lfloor x \rfloor^3+1$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer part of $x$, and $\lbrace x \rbrace $ its fractionnal part.

Comment: But how to think this horrible type function .

Comment: Whether there exist simple looking function...?

Comment: It is basically the same idea as lulu's comment, in an explicit form.

Comment: Ohh. Trying to understand.